# MergeResults plugin throws Error parsing field 'timeStamp' at line 1. java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

When I tried to do merge using `MergeResults plugin` it throws error:

```
Error parsing field 'timeStamp' at line 1. java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:"
```

TWO AggregateReport JTL files successfully converted into csv using the below CMD runner command

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv  E:\JMETER\PROJECT_NGP\Results\SL_Rel\Build_165-20749\Reports_09-05-2017-17-07-07\NGP_LoadTest_Results_AgReport.csv   --input-jtl E:\JMETER\PROJECT_NGP\Results\SL_Rel\Build_165-20749\Reports_09-05-2017-17-07-07\NGP_LoadTest_Results_AgReport.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

**Below is the error log details from jmeter.log file**

```
2017-09-06 12:35:40,963 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: E:\JMETER\PROJECT_NGP\Results\SL_Rel\Build_165-20749\Reports_09-05-2017-17-07-07\NGP_LoadTest_Results_AgReport.csv does not appear to have a valid header. Using default configuration.
2017-09-06 12:35:40,963 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Error parsing field 'timeStamp' at line 1. java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "sampler_label,aggregate_report_count,average,aggregate_report_median,aggregate_report_90%_line,aggregate_report_95%_line,aggregate_report_99%_line,aggregate_report_min,aggregate_report_max,aggregate_report_error%,aggregate_report_rate,aggregate_report_bandwidth,aggregate_report_stddev"
2017-09-06 12:35:40,963 WARN o.a.j.r.ResultCollector: Problem reading JTL file: E:\JMETER\PROJECT_NGP\Results\SL_Rel\Build_165-20749\Reports_09-05-2017-17-07-07\NGP_LoadTest_Results_AgReport.csv
2017-09-06 12:35:40,963 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Unknown column name sampler_label,aggregate_report_count,average,aggregate_report_median,aggregate_report_90%_line,aggregate_report_95%_line,aggregate_report_99%_line,aggregate_report_min,aggregate_report_max,aggregate_report_error%,aggregate_report_rate,aggregate_report_bandwidth,aggregate_report_stddev
```

In **user.properties file and properties** file timestamp settings are same(see the below screenshots).

Not able to figured it out what was wrong, Please advise.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the raw jtl files it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter configuration on the machine where you are doing results merge must match configuration of the machine where tests were executed. If there are inconsistencies the majority of [JMeter Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) will fail, neither you will be able to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

For example I see in your *user.properties* file the following issues:

1. You have duplicate `jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format` property settings defining different timestamp formats
2. You have `jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter` property set to `\t` while your results file is comma-separated

So you need to inspect JMeter's configuration of the machine where you are trying to merge results and make it inline with the machine where you ran the test.

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: JMeter configuration on the machine where you are doing results merge must match configuration of the machine where tests were executed-Both are on  same machine. #1.I will comment out 'ms'.#2.Not sure why results file generated in comma though I have mentioned \t in user.properties and JMeter.properties files as I wanted the results in \t format instead of  comma format-Raj

Comment: #1.I have commented 'ms' #2.Converted AggregateReport.csv still generates in comma format. Interestingly View Results in Tree.csv and  View Results in Table.csv  files are generated in tab format.Still getting the timestamp parse error.I have double checked user.properties file and jmeter.properties file both are having same config for timestamp and default_delimiter.                                                                                         I am stuck ,I Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I would recommend disabling or removing all the listeners for the duration of your load test, they don't add any value and [greatly increase memory consumption](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing). So all you need to go is to [run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like `jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl` and use this **result.jtl** file for any further analysis.

Comment: I have realized I should send raw jtl or csv as input files.